# Hovering stacked transparents images

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a few images stacked. Every image has some transparent pixels. Using only CSS can we use the hover property on images that aren't the higher one? When a pixel on the higher image is transparent the image that has to receive the "hover" event should be the next one whose this pixel is not transparent.

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/qny79r13/.

HTML :

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="Map%20base.png">
    <img src="Cavernes.png">
    <img src="Chemins.png">
    <img src="Points%20d'intérêt.png">
    <img src="Villes.png">
</div>
```

CSS :

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

img:hover {
    border: red 2px solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If it is not possible using only CSS, is there a way to do this with JS? Some articles talk about using SVG but I don't want to convert my images to SVG...

Thanks!

Comment: CSS can't tell you if there's a "non-transparent" pixel under your cursor. It's a simple hit test where ALL pixels make up the bounds of an image. SVG would allow you to test against individual elements.

Comment: @BryceHowitson > Thanks for the reply! I then have to convert my images to SVG. Do you know if there is there any simple way to do so?

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? There are always multiple solutions. In your map example. I'd absolutely place the markers instead of stacking lots of larger images.

Comment: The idea is to have an interactive map showing points of interest when hovering. I had a single image with all of these points and the easier solution I found was to cut it to isolate points. Using markers would be a solution but I would have to get the position of all points and that would be painful - I mean, more painful than cutting the original image.

Comment: I suggest updating your question to reflect this ^^ I'll attempt to provide a few solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Bryce Howitson said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57208732/hovering-stacked-transparents-images#comment100923996_57208732), it isn't possible using plain CSS. So I find a solution using JS. The trick is to use canvas to draw the image and use the 'onmousemove' event to find which pixel is hovered. If the pixel of the higher layer is transparent, the event is transmitted to the next layer. And so on to the last one.

Here is some working code:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
}

canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.hovered {
    border: red 2px solid;
}
```

JS:

```
const images = ["Map%20base.png",
    "Cavernes.png",
    "Chemins.png",
    "Points%20d'intérêt.png",
    "Villes.png"
];

const canvasList = [

];

const cssClasses = {
    hovered: 'hovered'
};

function loadImages(container) {
    for(const image of images) {
        const imageContainer = document.createElement('img');
        imageContainer.onload = (img) => {
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = imageContainer.width;
            canvas.height = imageContainer.height;
            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(imageContainer, 0, 0, imageContainer.width, imageContainer.height);
            canvas.onmouseover = onhover;
            canvas.onmousemove = onhover;

            container.appendChild(canvas);
            canvasList.push(canvas);
        };
        imageContainer.src = image;
    }
}

function onhover({target, offsetX, offsetY}) {
    if (!target) return;

    const color = target
        .getContext('2d')
        .getImageData(offsetX, offsetY, 1, 1)
        .data;

    for(const canvas of canvasList) {
        canvas.classList.remove(cssClasses.hovered);
    }

    if (color[3] === 0) {   // Transparent
        const nextCanvas = findNextCanvas(target);
        if (nextCanvas !== null) {
            onhover({target: nextCanvas, offsetX, offsetY});
        }
    } else {
        target.classList.add(cssClasses.hovered);
    }
}

function findNextCanvas(currentCanvas) {
    for(let i in canvasList) {
        if (canvasList[i] === currentCanvas) {
            if (i === 0) return null;
            else return canvasList[i - 1];
        }
    }

    return null;
}

loadImages(document.getElementById('container'));
```

Hope this helps someone else! :)

Comment: Well done. The SVG solution would have been similar except that it requires converting each element into its own positioned image inside the SVG bounds.